# Need to copy the contents of a vertical cell into a horizontal cell and then copy the formula horizontal and have it update the references

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference, cell

I want a formula in columns `B$10,C$10`...to reference the cells in rows 
`$A3,$A4`... and the same for columns `B$11,C$11`... etc..

Columns Values

```
alpha   'now                
,bravo  ',is                
,charlie    ',the               
,david  ',time              
,egert  ',for
```

.

```
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE(  alpha   ,bravo  ,charlie    ,david  egert)
VALUES( 'now'   ,'is'   ,'the'  ,'time' ,'for')
```

But how do i increment the cell references by one down a column and 
across a row?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question. It's a very poor form of asking the question. The actual question is how to generate SQL Insert query in Excel using formulas? Just providing an image is not enough. Try Copying the data and while pasting use the PasteSpecial option and then click on Transpose.

Comment: I was confused with the editor.  It has a link now to the photo.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Place this in cells `B10:F10` as an array formula (Ctrl-Shift-Enter to complete), and copy down

```
=INDEX($3:$7,COLUMN()-1,ROW()-9)
```

`INDEX` returns a cell from an array, in this case rows 3 to 7.  The second and third parameters specify the row and column in that array to return.  `COLUMN()` and `ROW()` return the column or row number of the cell the formula is in, in this case cells `B10:F10`.  Referring to Row by Column number and Column by Row number causes to the data to transpose.

So, for example consider cell `C10`:  `COLUMN()` = 3, `ROW()` = 10, so `INDEX($3:$7,3-1,10-9)` refers to cell 2nd row, 1st column of `$3:$7`ie `A4`

Comment: Thank you Chris!  This worked like a charm.  Unfortunately I can't give you an upvote because I do not have enough "points"?

Comment: Now if I could figure out what this does.  Could you explain the logic?  You are using the Column() in place of the Row() in the index function and subtracting 1 and vice versa, the Row() in place of the Column() and subtracting 9.  If I had time, I would play with it, but you obviously have a better command.

Comment: @brian added some explanation to the answer